# Trouble Installing PyOpenGLContext (Syntax Error)

Tags: python, opengl, installation, pyopengl

I've recently decided to learn OpenGl in python.

I installed PyOpenGL using `pip3 install PyOpenGl PyOpenGl_accelerate`. I was then about to follow a
  [tutorial](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/tutorials/nehe1.html) for PyOpenGL. The first item was to install PyOpenGLContext.

I tried to install PyOpenGLContext with both `pip3 install OpenGLContext` and `pip3 install PyDispatcher PyVRML97 OpenGLContext` and both gave me the same error:

```
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/3r/xfny397j6j98y1sjgh_s574m0000gn/T/pip-build-o7zx54vx/OpenGLContext/setup.py", line 10
    except ImportError, err:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, there's a syntax error there. How do I get around this? If you need more information, please let me know. I am trying to install this on a MacBook Pro (2013) version for Python3.5.

Answer (score 4):

It should work if you download and install the wheel from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/):

1. Download the **OpenGLContext‑2.3.0‑py2.py3‑none‑any.whl** installation file to a an arbitrary directory.
2. `cd` to that directory in a command line and install using `pip install OpenGLContext‑2.3.0‑py2.py3‑none‑any.whl`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like OpenGLContext has not been updated in a while, and thus is not compatible with Python 3.5.

Having a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/OpenGLContext yields that the last update was in 2014.

You probably want to either use an older python version, or a different library.

Comment: I've done some basic graphics for FLTK (I didn't like that library) in C++ and I'd like to learn some graphics in Python. Do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: I'll go ahead and guess your answer is Tcl/Tk. I'll start there.

Comment: @K.Shores if you like python, really have a look at Panda3D (Don't get scared by the website). Its a full game engine though, so not sure if thats already too high-level.

Comment: That's not. I'm in my sophomore year of college. I won't be focusing on graphics in my course work, but I still want to get familiar with graphics.